# How to rotate a bitmap by 90 degrees and get a valid metafile

Tags: c, windows, gdi

I am using PlgBlt to rotate a Windows bitmap over 90 degrees. This works fine when displaying the map on screen, but inspecting an enhanced metafile made of this process shows the rotated bitmap completely missing.

Rotated text (with CreateFontIndirect()), output through TextOut(), is also missing from the enhanced metafile. A simple bitmap rotation/flip routine combined with StretchBlt() works fine.

PlgBlt is using a device-dependent bitmap, while an enhanced metafile is supposed to be device-independent. Could that be it?

Comment: The second point just says that you cannot use `PlgBlt` to create an EMF from another EMF -- did you try using a `DIB` to create your EMF?

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that it meant just that (no recursion/re-entrancy allowed).